# Raspberry Pi auto login and run script in screen

Tags: debian, bash, gnu-screen

so i'm trying to make it so i can just plug in my raspberry pi. It will automatically login to the user "pi" then run a script which starts a screen under a certain name and runs a python file within that screen.

I have followed [this tutorial](http://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/raspberry-pi/5/raspberry-pi-auto-start.html), but am unsure weather or not it has worked and not sure how to test it.

I edited /etc/profile and added the line

```
. /home/pi/autoStartSafeMonitor.sh
```

to it and in that sh file i have

```
#!/bin/bash -e
screen -d -m -S SAFE /home/pi/CONTROL-AUTO.py
```

I rebooted my pi and the script detected an rfid scanner input and changed a servo, this script works when i run it manually but it does not seem to be activated when the pi boots up. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to install your script as a service on the system and not disable login.